# Search engine to integrate in a .NET stack

Tags: c#, search, full-text-search, search-engine

I am looking for a very robust software search engine to integrate in a .Net web site.

The current proposed solution is <strike>Lucene.NET</strike> a stack based on Lucene. However, I would like to evaluate other search engines before making my mind up.

The feature set we need is the following:

- Ability to crawl arbitrary pages via HTTP
- Ability to parse sitemaps
- Ability to get lists of URIs to parse via a database look-up
- Ability to restrict the search to a particular language/locale
- Ability to restrict the search to a subset of the pages (e.g. via a regex on the URI)
- Speed and scalability (this is for a public website with a ton of traffic)
- Must have .NET API support or a super-easy http-based API that can be wrapped in a .NET API
- Language-dependent full-text support

Other things which would be great, but not deal-breakers if they aren't supported:

- Reporting
- Aliasing and biasing of results
- HTTP-based administration pages
- SQL Server support

What other software search engines have worked for you? Is there any you would recommend or that we should avoid?

Answer (score 3):

Lucene.Net is an information retrieval library, not a search engine.  In particular it **won't** do any of:

- Crawl web pages or parse sitemaps
- Reporting
- HTTP-based administration pages
- SQL Server support (Lucene.Net uses its own simple but highly effective file format, and doesn't use SQL Server)

Although I'm a strong supporter or SQL and would recommend it as the full-text search component of a search engine, you will also need a crawler / html parser component in order to create a full functional search engine, and you are going to have to carefully design your Lucene.Net indexes to maximise the performance of the queries that you want (searching by language/locale)

Try looking at the [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) project which is a fully fledged search engine using Lucene - this might be more suited towards your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Microsoft's [Search Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/search-server-express.aspx), although the page looks screwed up at the moment so try this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dfd0cfac-f52c-4c02-a972-0e4f1c4e7977&displaylang=en).

There's other enterprise engines out there such as [vivisimo velocity](http://vivisimo.com) (very extensible), autonomy, etc. Lucene and Solr are limited, hard to use and configure, but that's what you get when you want something free.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). It's Java-based, but meets the HTTP-based API leg of your requirements, is designed to run on a separate box/cluster from your primary app (so you don't necessarily need Java AND .NET on the same hardware), and it has a lot of momentum. It's been a while since I worked with it, but I don't remember it providing it's own crawler. If that's still the case, it should be straightforward to use a standalone crawler and the aforementioned API to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Lucene.Net directly, have you considered using something that wraps it and provides more functionality akin to what you're after?

[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is an Apache product that does this, and there is also a [.Net client](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) <strike>port of</strike> for it. I've never used it in production, but it looks like the type of thing you're after.

Along a similar idea is [Nutch](http://nutch.sourceforge.net) (written by the guy who originally wrote Lucene), although I'm not aware of any .Net version of it. Nutch does have a spider component to crawl sites.

Comment: Solrnet is not a .net port of Solr, it's a client library.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, definitley go with the original Lucene using Solr. Integrating it with .Net is super simple. I actually just recently blogged about this: http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2010/01/full-text-search-using-solr-lucene-and.html

Answer (score 1):

[Coveo](http://www.coveo.com/) is the search engine that we are currently putting in to replace a [Google Mini](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/mini.html) that was used for a number of years.  I'm just pointing these out as something to explore as I haven't used either enough to know how good they are.  I just know of headaches with each, many many headaches.

Answer (score 1):

You may also have a look at [OpenSearchServer](http://www.open-search-server.com)

Runs like a charm on Windows. You can use the SOAP Web service to do the integration.

There is also a C# skeleton library working with the XML/REST API.

*Disclaimer: I am the CEO of OpenSearchServer*

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thank you for your notice. After reading carefully the FAQ, especially the "May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?" topic, I was not able to find any detail about that kind of disclaimer. What is a good practice ?

Comment: Adjust this for whatever your appropriate role is, but something like: "Disclaimer: I am the Lead of the OpenSearchServer team", posted right after the link or any mention of it. Note that this isn't important when someone is asking a question *specifically about* how to do something on any of your products, "How do I sprug my sprockets with OpenSearchServer?" - you can answer that sort of "Help" question without disclosure.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, you could simply fix it yourself, as I did - this site is collaboratively edited :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz I was mostly hoping to get the point across for the future. I also was not initially 100% sure he was affiliated with it (just mostly sure! hehe). But that's a good point nonetheless :-)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I will do that now. Three comments: 1.I am not a marketer. 2. The web site of OpenSearchServer is on my public profile since the origin. 3.The answer was relevant. ;-)

Comment: @EmmanuelKeller re #3, I know; If it wasn't relevant, I would have simply flagged as spam and forgotten about it. re #1, #2; both of those are fine, of course. But note that the requirement is still that you disclose in your answers when you mention/link to the product/website, since many readers don't look closely at profiles or even user names. Anyway; keep that in mind, and keep your answers relevant, and there won't be any problem at all :)

Comment: (Incidentally; I'm checking out the product myself for possible future use)